# Enter value A and B, then C = A+B, store A, B, C in database. Update value A or B will update sum C in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just to simplify my question here: [Update Geocode latitude and logitude everytime address is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034050/update-geocode-latitude-and-longitude-everytime-address-is-updated)

I wanna do this:

Two input field for user to enter values for A, B. When it is saved, value A and B are saved to the database. In the database column, there is a column C, which dynamically C = A + B.

First save:

A = 1
B = 2
C = A + B = 3

Then when user updates value for A and B, C is also changed dynamically and replace the new sum value in the database.

A = 2
B = 2
Now C will calculate: C = A + B = 4

Now value C is 4 instead of 3.

Can anyone write this thing in Rails? Thanks.

Comment: "Can anyone write this thing in Rails" - isn't that your job?

Comment: I'm sort of like learning Rails on reverse-engineering method, by no choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can!

The key are callbacks. This will update C before you save the object.

```
before_save :update_c

def update_c
  self.c = a + b
end
```

Comment: But if the entry is new? Then the first save will give problem, won't it?

Comment: Dude, I think you roughly saved my life by half at the moment. I am checking out callbacks and they look promising to what I have been looking for hours! Thanks! I'm a noob in Ruby on Rails, and am learning it by "reverse engineering" method which I have no choice!

Comment: Should I enter this in model or controller?

Comment: You probably should pick up a Rails book :) Agile Web Development With Rails explains it all to you.

Comment: Half way then I stopped, but will do it again when I have time. Appreciate your advice and help all over SO!

Answer (score 1):

In your model

```
 before_save :calculate_c

 def calculate_c
    self.c = self.a + self.b
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

forgive me for asking, but why store C in the first place? Won't having a and b on hand always satisfy c?

Comment: Yes, but in this case the poster wants to geo-encode an address to lat,lng - the a-b-c is just an abstraction of that problem. Having lat,lng in you db for queries is much easier.

Comment: I still don't follow. Whatever method used to extract a and b can then calculate c dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this is a design smell.
If the value of C is always A + B, then there is no need to store it in the database at all.
Either the code that retrieves A & B can do the calculation, or a suitable database query can fetch A & B and calculate the value of C, before returning all three to the calling code.

But, given that A & B are latitude & longitude and C is and address, I may be wrong.